# mysql query select just last record by time

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:
table **exchaneRate**

```
╔════╦══════════╦══════════════╦═════╦══════╦══════════════════╗
║ id ║ officeID ║ currencyCode ║ buy ║ sell ║ startDateTime    ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 01 ║  off_1   ║       AA     ║  65 ║  75  ║ 2015═10═01 12:00 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 02 ║  off_1   ║       BB     ║  64 ║  73  ║ 2015═10═01 12:00 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 03 ║  off_1   ║       AA     ║  55 ║  65  ║ 2015═09═25 12:00 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 04 ║  off_1   ║       BB     ║  54 ║  63  ║ 2015═09═25 12:00 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 05 ║  off_1   ║       AA     ║  30 ║  42  ║ 2015═09═15 12:00 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 06 ║  off_1   ║       BB     ║  40 ║  48  ║ 2015═09═15 12:00 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 07 ║  off_2   ║       AA     ║  65 ║  75  ║ 2015═10═01 12:00 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═════╬══════╬══════════════════╣
║ 08 ║  off_2   ║       BB     ║  65 ║  75  ║ 2015═10═01 12:00 ║
╚════╩══════════╩══════════════╩═════╩══════╩══════════════════╝
```

And I have request like this to select data:

```
    select `currencyCode`, `buy`, `sell` from `exchangeRate` 
where `officeID` = 'off_1' and startDateTime <= '2015-09-30 00:00';
```

And I want this result:

```
╔══════════════╦═════╦══════╗
║ currencyCode ║ buy ║ sell ║
╠══════════════╬═════╬══════╣
║       AA     ║  55 ║  65  ║
╠══════════════╬═════╬══════╣
║       BB     ║  54 ║  63  ║
╚══════════════╩═════╩══════╝
```

But request returns all record AA, BB, AA, BB, AA, BB... from table. But I need just last records for each `currencyCode` for this `officeID`. 
How can I do that?

Comment: It is not clear how you are creating your result set.  How do you want to choose one record for each `currencyCode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the following approach.  The inner query determines the records you want for each `currencyCode` using your time range.  The original `exchangeRate` table is then filtered on this inner query through an `INNER JOIN` to give the output you want.

```
SELECT t1.currencyCode, t1.buy, t1.sell
FROM exchangeRate t1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT currencyCode, MAX(startDateTime) AS maxTime
    FROM exchangeRate
    WHERE startDateTime <= '2015-09-30 00:00' AND officeID = 'off_1'
    GROUP BY currencyCode
) t2
ON t1.currencyCode = t2.currencyCode AND t1.startDateTime = t2.maxTime
```

Click below for a running demo.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99d9360/6)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99d9360/3 if table contains just one record - request returns nothing

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition is time < `2015-09-30`.  My query _should_ return no records in this case.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake (

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
select `currencyCode`, `buy`, `sell` from `exchangeRate` 
where id in 
( select max(id) from exchangeRate  
   where `officeID` = 'off_1' and startDateTime <= '2015-09-30 00:00' group by currencyCode 
)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f661/8)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT currencyCode,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(buy ORDER BY startDateTime DESC),',',1) as buy_1,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sell ORDER BY startDateTime DESC),',',1) as sell_1,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(startDateTime ORDER BY startDateTime DESC),',',1) as date_1 
FROM exchangeRate
WHERE officeID = 'off_1'
GROUP BY currencyCode
HAVING date_1 <= '2015-09-30 00:00'
ORDER BY currencyCode
```